# Is there any possible ways to develop JSF based web application by using a template designed in HTML5 and CSS?

Tags: css, html, jsf, xhtml

I have a template which is designed in HTML5 and CSS. How can I use this template to develop a web application in JSF. Is there any possibilities to change my HTML5 template to XHTML. Because JSF works in XHTML.
Please can anyone help me in this question to develop my web application?
Advanced thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4793959/1391249

Comment: @Tiny: I think OP means template like used for CMS systems etc... So  the html5-friendly markup for jsf is more appropriate here (but that is just my interpretation)